# Studio-Controls Not starting. Ubuntu Studio 21.10

Tags: upgrade, sound

Ubuntu Studio Upgraded from 21.04 to 21.10 (64bit)
21.04 had been working correctly.
On starting Studio-control; The upgrade will show the Studio-control Icon in the top bar for a second then not.
Jack has not started.
Carla shows no connection.
Opening Ardour: I can start Jack from the Ardour setup screen. Carla now responds correctly with the patching diagram. Attempting to start Studio-control with Jack running has no effect.

Should I attempt to reload Studio-control from synaptic, and if so any other files at the same time?
Any other suggestions?
Note: I made a similar upgrade from Ubuntu Studio 21.04 to 21.10 on a laptop and that runs very well.